# How to hide :after, when hovering over parent element?

Tags: css

I have a div `#header` which has an opaque gradient. This div has an `:after` which is another opaque gradient to give the div a 3d look. When hovering over the `#header` I want to hide the `:after` is it possible to do this with CSS or would this require JS?

Comment: create a fiddle then we may be able to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
#header:hover:after {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: This place is amazing..very helpful people..Thanks Russ!